# Display message using view bag without refreshing view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view A From ControllerA Which has two buttons 1. Create 2. Update

Upon clicking  update or Create its opening a new partial viewB As popup from another controller B.

What iam trying to get is If a record is created successfully in b I am now closing the popup. Apart from closing the popup I want to display a message in view A.

I am trying like this:
Controller B

```
      public ActionResult Create(FormCollection args)
    {
        var obj = new ProjectManagernew();

        var res = new ProjectViewModelNew();
        try
        {
            UpdateModel(res);
            if (obj.AddUpdateOrderField(res))
            {
                ViewBag.RecordAdded = true;
                ViewBag.Message = "Project Added Successfully";

            }
            return View(res);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //ModelState.AddRuleViolations(res.GetRuleViolations());
            return View(res);
        }
    }
```

And in the view A:

```
@if(ViewBag.Message!=null)
{
@ViewBag.Message
}
```

View B:

```
@model DreamTrade.Web.BL.ViewModels.ProjectViewModelNew

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_Popup.cshtml";
}
@if (ViewBag.RecordAdded != null && (bool)ViewBag.RecordAdded)
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.$.nmTop().close();
 $('#jqgprojectnew').text("Record added successfully");//jqgprojectnew is the name of grid in view A
</script>
 }
   <h2>Create</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Project</legend>
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectDetail)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectDetail)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectDetail)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectRef)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectRef)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectRef)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectName)
    </div>

   <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusList)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectStatusId,new SelectList(Model.StatusList,"SourceStatusId","Description"),"Please Select")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectStatusId)
    </div>

     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerList)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id,new SelectList(Model.CustomerList,"Id","Name"),"Please Select")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
 <div>
 <a href="javascript:parent.$.nmTop().close()">Back to list</a>
 </div>

 @section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

please let me know where iam doing wrong

Comment: Try this 
@if(ViewBag.Message!=null)
{
<span>@ViewBag.Message</span>
}

If not working please tell me

Comment: No Amit Agrawal no luck same old message is not displaying

Comment: use this - return View("ViewA",res);

Comment: Plz include the ajax code you used to post the form to action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a label field where you want to show the message.

```
<label id=mylabel></label>// Add this before jqgrid
```

Modify the code to:

```
@if (ViewBag.RecordAdded != null && (bool)ViewBag.RecordAdded)
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.$.nmTop().close();
    $('#mylabel').text("Record added successfully");
</script>
 }
```

Comment: I want to display message in viewA not in view B

Comment: Where do you want to dispaly the message?

Comment: plz post the ajax code for posting the form, so that I can help you more

Comment: Does this part work? @if (ViewBag.RecordAdded != null && (bool)ViewBag.RecordAdded)
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.$.nmTop().close();
</script>
 }

Comment: Then why dont you just alert ""Project Added Successfully" there itself?

Comment: Or if you want it as a label on top of jqgrid, set its text() to this message. I mean, $('#label').text("Added Successfully");

Comment: You cant set the text for jqgrid. You should create  label and name it

Comment: Where did you add the label field?

Comment: Above the jq grid <div>
    <div>Projects(<div id="count" style="display: inline;"></div> items)</div>
    <label id=mylabel></label>
    <table id="jqgprojectnew" style="width: 100%">
    </table>
    @*<div id="jqgp" style="text-align: center;">
        </div>*@
    <br />
  
    <div class="clear">
    </div>

Comment: label id should be in quotes. And did you really edited this line $('#jqgprojectnew').text("Record added successfully");  to   $('#mylabel').text("Record added successfully");'

Comment: try alerting the message.ie; alert("Record added successfully") instead of this line: $('#mylabel').text("Record added successfully");'